# Matrix Multiplication in Apache Spark

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, rdd, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to perform matrix multiplication using Apache Spark and Java.

I have 2 main questions:

1. How to create RDD that can represent matrix in Apache Spark?
2. How to multiply two such RDDs?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

All depends on the input data and dimensions but generally speaking what you want is not a `RDD` but one of the distributed data structures from [`org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.package). At this moment it provides four different implementations of the [`DistributedMatrix`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/distributed/DistributedMatrix.html)

- [`IndexedRowMatrix`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/distributed/IndexedRowMatrix.html) - can be created directly from a `RDD[IndexedRow]` where [`IndexedRow`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/distributed/IndexedRow.html) consist of row index and `org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector`

  ```
  import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Vectors, Matrices}
  import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.{IndexedRowMatrix,
    IndexedRow}

  val rows =  sc.parallelize(Seq(
    (0L, Array(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)),
    (0L, Array(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)),
    (0L, Array(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)))
  ).map{case (i, xs) => IndexedRow(i, Vectors.dense(xs))}

  val indexedRowMatrix = new IndexedRowMatrix(rows)
  ```
- [`RowMatrix`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/distributed/RowMatrix.html) - similar to `IndexedRowMatrix` but without meaningful row indices. Can be created directly from `RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector]`

  ```
  import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix

  val rowMatrix = new RowMatrix(rows.map(_.vector))
  ```
- [`BlockMatrix`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/distributed/BlockMatrix.html) - can be created from `RDD[((Int, Int), Matrix)]` where first element of the tuple contains coordinates of the block and the second one is a local `org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Matrix`

  ```
  val eye = Matrices.sparse(
    3, 3, Array(0, 1, 2, 3), Array(0, 1, 2), Array(1, 1, 1))

  val blocks = sc.parallelize(Seq(
     ((0, 0), eye), ((1, 1), eye), ((2, 2), eye)))

  val blockMatrix = new BlockMatrix(blocks, 3, 3, 9, 9)
  ```
- [`CoordinateMatrix`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.CoordinateMatrix) - can be created from `RDD[MatrixEntry]` where [`MatrixEntry`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.MatrixEntry) consist of row, column and value.

  ```
  import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.{CoordinateMatrix,
    MatrixEntry}

  val entries = sc.parallelize(Seq(
     (0, 0, 3.0), (2, 0, -5.0), (3, 2, 1.0),
     (4, 1, 6.0), (6, 2, 2.0), (8, 1, 4.0))
  ).map{case (i, j, v) => MatrixEntry(i, j, v)}

  val coordinateMatrix = new CoordinateMatrix(entries, 9, 3)
  ```

First two implementations support multiplication by a local `Matrix`:

```
val localMatrix = Matrices.dense(3, 2, Array(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0))

indexedRowMatrix.multiply(localMatrix).rows.collect
// Array(IndexedRow(0,[1.0,4.0]), IndexedRow(0,[2.0,5.0]),
//   IndexedRow(0,[3.0,6.0]))
```

and the third one can be multiplied by an another `BlockMatrix` as long as number of columns per block in this matrix matches number of rows per block of the other matrix. `CoordinateMatrix` doesn't support multiplications but is pretty easy to create and transform to other types of distributed matrices:

```
blockMatrix.multiply(coordinateMatrix.toBlockMatrix(3, 3))
```

Each type has its own strong and weak sides and there are some additional factors to consider when you use sparse or dense elements (`Vectors` or block `Matrices`). Multiplying by a local matrix is usually preferable since it doesn't require expensive shuffling.

You can find more details about each type in [the MLlib Data Types guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-data-types.html).

Comment: This is a great summary for how to create the different matrix types -- I think I'm going to bookmark this!

Comment: What are the `BlockMatrix` parameters used for? Also I see multiply can take an int param? I am having trouble trying to multiply 250k x 30k X 30k x 30k

Comment: Here is the question though, even though you can do matrix multiplication in spark, should you?  It seems like so many other libraries in the C world do matrix multiplication much better, like in deep learning libraries and such.  They even leverage distributed GPU processing in some cases.  How much less efficient is matrix operations in spark?

Comment: I found this very useful.  The users who closed this question are doing a disservice.

Comment: I would like to know which one scales better if, for instance, you would use it for `columnSimilarities`?