# How to perform matrix dot product with a vector using Spark's RDD

Tags: matrix, vector, apache-spark

There is a matrix and I want to perform the dot product of it with a vector. Following is the Scala code:

```
val matrix = sc.parallelize(List(
  (("v1","v1"),2),(("v1","v2"),4),(("v1","v3"),1),(("v2","v2"),5),
  (("v2","v3"),1),(("v3","v3"),2)))

val vector = sc.parallelize(List(("v1",4),("v2",1),("v3",5)))

val dotproduct = matrix.flatMap{x => { 
  vector.flatMap { y => { 
    if(x._1._2 == y._1) Tuple2(x._1._1, x._2 * y._2)
  }}
}}.reduceByKey((_,_) => _+_)
```

But the following error occurred:

```
<console>:25: error: type mismatch;
found   : (String, Int)
required: TraversableOnce[?]
val dotproduct = matrix.flatMap{ x => { vector.flatMap { y => { if(x._1._2 == y._1) (x._1._1, x._2 * y._2) }}}}.reduceByKey((_,_) => _+_)
                                                                                         ^
```

I don't know if the nesting operation in RDD is OK. Does Spark MLlib provide any API to perform the dot product between matrix and vector?

Comment: The matrix is symmetrical, so I only used the elements above the diagonals.

Answer (score 3):

> I don't know if the nesting operation in RDD is OK.

It is not OK. Spark doesn't support nested actions, transformations or distributed data structures.

> Does Spark MLlib provide any API to perform the dot product between matrix and vector?

`RowMatrix` provides `multiply` method which accepts a local matrix. It should work just fine in your case.

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.{CoordinateMatrix, MatrixEntry}

val idx = "^v([0-9]+)$".r

val rdd = sc.parallelize(List(
  (("v1", "v1"), 2), (("v1", "v2"), 4),
  (("v1", "v3"), 1), (("v2", "v2"), 5),
  (("v2", "v3"), 1), (("v3", "v3"), 2)
))

val mat = new CoordinateMatrix(rdd.map { case ((idx(i), idx(j)), v) => 
  MatrixEntry(i.toLong - 1, j.toLong - 1, v.toDouble)
}).toIndexedRowMatrix

val vector =  Matrices.dense(3, 1, Array(4.0, 1.0, 5.0))
mat.multiply(vector).rows
```

If vector is to large to be handled in memory you can use block matrices. See [Matrix Multiplication in Apache Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33558755/1560062)

Regarding your code you can for example do something like this:

```
matrix
  .map{case ((i, j), v) => (j, (i, v))}
  .join(vector)
  .values
  .map{case ((i, v1), v2) => (i, v1 * v2)}
  .reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

or with local "vector" (optionally broadcasted):

```
val vector = Map(("v1" -> 4), ("v2" -> 1), ("v3" -> 5)).withDefault(_ => 0)

matrix.map{case ((i, j), v) => (i, v * vector(j))}.reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

Comment: Thank you for clarification, zero323!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that by *dot product* you mean just the ordinary matrix-vector multiplication, you could use the `multiply` method from the `mllib.linalg` package

```
val mlMat=Matrices.dense(3,2,matrix.collect().map(_._2.toDouble)).transpose
val mlVect=Vectors.dense(vector.collect().map(_._2.toDouble))
mlMat.multiply(mlVect)
//org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.DenseVector = [17.0,31.0]
```