# How would one do operation involving a rdd inside the executors with mapPartition or such ?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to do something like that:

```
val myBigRdd2: RDD[_] = ???
myBigRdd1.mapPartition{ dataBlock => 
    // operation involving dataBlock and an other RDD
    // like myBigRdd2.multiply(dataBlock) 
    // if myBigRdd2 is a matrix. Or something similar.
}
```

is there a way of giving an RDD to the executor ?

I think `Broadcast` on `rdd2` won't work because it is too big.

And doing `collect` and `grouped` on the `rdd1` won't work either because the driver memory will blow up.

Is there any other way ?

`cartesian` work but takes forever.

Comment: No, there is not. But possibly related [Matrix Multiplication in Apache Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33558755/9613318)

Comment: I kind of found a way using `RandomSplit`, that give a `Seq[RDD]` and then I can collect the smaller one to create a new RDD , sequentially not to overload the driver and then `union` those.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass RDD to mapPartition as that is a structure only known to the driver. Executors cannot use the RDD structure.